# View Function Error in Ethers js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets

I Use ethersjs Cdn when i call getCounter Function in my SmartContract it return me transaction object not give me counter value. View Function not give me value it give me transaction object

```
async function connectMetamask() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        try {
            // Request Metamask to connect
            await window.ethereum.enable();
            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
             signer = provider.getSigner();
            userAddress = await signer.getAddress();
            console.log('Connected Address:', userAddress);
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
                    // Get the current counter value
                    const counterValue = await contract.getCounter();
                    console.log('Counter Value:', counterValue.toString());
                    document.getElementById('counterValue').textContent = counterValue.toString();
                       
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Metamask not found');
    }
}

// Call the connectMetamask function when the page is loaded
window.addEventListener('load', connectMetamask);
```

Comment: This is the exact same problem I was facing and I couldn't find any answer after trying so hard.

Comment: What value is contractAddress?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the function isn't specified as `view` in the ABI.

In any case, according to the [docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-callStatic) you can try forcing a call by adding `callStatic` before the call:

> Rather than executing the state-change of a transaction, it is possible to ask a node to pretend that a call is not state-changing and return the result.
> This does not actually change any state, but is free. This in some cases can be used to determine if a transaction will fail or succeed.
> This otherwise functions the same as a Read-Only Method.

Your call will be like this:

```js
const counterValue = await contract.callStatic.getCounter();
```

It should return a value and not the transaction object.